# Exporting ViewData\ModelState to Child Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As the subject says, is this a bad idea? If so, why?

Currently, if you are rendering some input fields from inside a @Html.Acion, the validation errors don't get displayed to the user as the ModelState gets cleared when the @Html.Action gets involved (in its context.)

So whats the best pattern around it?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it with child actions or partial views or in any other way?

Comment: I went ahead with partial views with the extra data being tacked onto ViewBag. A acceptable compromise in my opinion instead of trying to hack Html.Action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the parent contexts via `ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext` or `ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext` (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412310/how-to-get-current-controller-and-action-from-inside-child-action)) but I think there are better solutions.

A child action is a good choice when you do not want to pollute all of your view models with data which are available independent from the current controller action and view (for example a user welcome label, a navigation bar, etc.).

For other reuse scenarios like common input fields a partial view is a better approach.

However if you give more details about your current scenario I try to suggest a more specific solution.