# MVC get controller in helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to be able to get a controller name in my custom helper class.

I have the following:

1. Layout view which calls a controller: "HelperController", action: "Menu" like so:

`@Html.Action("Menu", "Helper")`

1. This calls ActionResult and generages an html:

   ```
   @model List<MvcMenuItem>
   @{
   Layout = null;
   }
   @{        
   @Html.Menu(this.ViewContext).ClientId("navMain").AddRange(Model).Render()
   }
   ```
2. This calls "`public static class MvcMenuExtensions`" and in there (in my `Render()` method) I need to be able to get the controller name I'm currently in, NOT the controller name that is calling `MvcMenuExtensions`

I've tried this:

```
string controller = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

but this results in controller being "`Helper`" controller and not the current controller I'm in. Since this "`ActionResult`" is being called from anywhere on the page (it's in the layout).

Thanks

Comment: This will probably provide answer to you question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412310/how-to-get-current-controller-and-action-from-inside-child-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered here: [How to get current controller and action from inside Child action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412310/how-to-get-current-controller-and-action-from-inside-child-action)
 by juhan_h

```
ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

OR

```
ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!