# Get controller name of outer view that called Html.RenderAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

Let's say I have these components:

```
ControllerA (ViewA) 
ControllerB (ViewB)
ControllerX (ViewX)
```

ViewA and ViewB embed a Html.RenderAction('ControllerX') in them.

I understand that from within ViewX, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] will give me "ControllerX"... and that completely makes sense.

**What I am wondering is, whether it's possible to get the value of the "outer" controller from within ViewX?**

In other words, if I'm in ViewX, is there a way for me to know whether I was rendered from ControllerA or ControllerB?

Reason being is that there are certain aspects within ViewX that I need to have dynamically built based on where it's coming from.  I'm pretty sure I can get this desired behavior using partial views and the necessary ViewModels but I like the approach of a self contained Rendered Action.

**[Update]**
Thanks to Stephen, I found the a duplicate question + answer here:

[How to get current controller and action from inside Child action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412310/how-to-get-current-controller-and-action-from-inside-child-action)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `ViewContext.ParentActionViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]`

Comment: Perfect!  I did a search with what you provided and found a duplicate answer.  Thanks for the guidance.  Feel free to submit as answer and I'll award the acceptance.